# Trying to understand the jQuery('#none') selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I am working on a small project for work and I came across a piece of code that is iterating a counter, and if that counter is not 0 then it executes this small bit of code:

```
if (cnt) jQuery('#none').prop('checked', false);
```

I am trying to understand what the jQuery('#none') selector is. When I execute it alone as just a selector within the chrome console, it returns an empty set. I have been googling for about 30 minutes, searching jQuery/JavaScript/CSS docs and all I can find are a few references to things where people are using this selector, but the topic in question is not in regard to the selector itself. To me this line appears to be doing literally nothing as commenting it out does not seem to change the behavior.

I really prefer to not mess around with stuff I don't understand as that almost always results in bugs. Can anyone point me to some documentation or just explain here what the #none selector is?

EDIT:
It would appear there is no magic #none selector. My assumption is this was left over from a previous iteration, it threw me off since the person who originally wrote it does not write erroneous code like this and I was finding people using the same selector online with no explanation - but those instances were red herrings.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/. There's nothing special about the term `none`, it's just what someone in that project chose as an identifier for some element.

Comment: It’s just a normal ID. #none is probably a control that gets unchecked if any other values a checked.

Comment: I guess they are selecting element like this with ID none: `<input type="checkbox" id="none" value="some checkbox">`

Comment: @Bergi yes I am pretty familiar with selectors overall. I guess my confusion was coming from the fact that there is never an instance of something with an ID of none in this application, and the person who wrote this snippet does not write erroneous code so it threw me off when I found it. It must have gotten left in from a previous iteration of this project I guess

Comment: @Turk Everyone makes mistakes from time to time and writes erroneous code (even me - I wouldn't believe it! :P).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not show any research effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery('#none') selects all elements where id=none. If there are no elements with the id of "none", then it will return an empty set.

```
<div id=none>This div has the id = "none"</div>
```

It sounds like you found a piece of 'cruft' (aka zombie code).

Comment: yeah that's what it appears like, thanks for the answer. I've become too complicit that my boss writes perfect code all the time and it's me that doesn't always understand it, but even he is fallible it would appear haha